# Can spaCy's entities (using EntityRuler) be made time-dependent?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I would like to make specific entities in spaCy (by specific I mean .ent_id) dependent on a custom property of the doc (the time the article underlying the doc was published). To give an example, take the hypothetical patterns format:

```
patterns = [
   {"label": "PERSON", "pattern": "Ronaldo", "id": "CR7", "start":"2008", "end":"2021"},
   {"label": "PERSON", "pattern": "Ronaldo", "id": "R9", "start":"1996", "end":"2007"},
]
```

So if the doc is from, say, 2005, mentions to *Ronaldo* would yield **R9** while an article from 2018 would yield **CR7**.

I could probably write a custom pipeline, but is there something easier / more appropriate (perhaps simply post-processing with a dictionary would make more sense)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against doc properties with patterns.

I would just use a component to post-process things here. Something that iterates over the doc and for any entity adds the ID by checking the year.

If your matches are all literal strings that should be pretty easy. If you have more complicated patterns and resolving the match back to the pattern isn't easy, I would use intermediate IDs that you can then use to resolve your year.